# "what to make of it" means "what to make with it"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

> Children who are "crying or making loud noises" are not allowed inside
>   Old Fisherman's Grotto. The restaurant is serious about this policy —
>   and **people aren't sure what to make of it**. ([source](http://www.thisisinsider.com/california-restaurant-doesnt-allow-children-making-loud-noises-2018-5))

Since this structure isn't parallel to something in my native language, I'm not sure what it means, but it seems that the meaning of it is like "what to do with it", or "what to do about it". Isn't it?

If it is, then can I use both interchangeably? ("what to make of it" and "what to make with it")?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, the phrasal verb make of has meaning 2 from the [Macmillan Dictionary](https://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/make-of):

> to understand someone or the meaning of something in a particular way

So, if people don't know what to make of something, it means they don't understand it: in this case, it probably means that they don't know how to react to it.

On the other hand, **make ... with** would be the literal meaning of **make**: here is a suitable dictionary from the [Cambridge Dictionary](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/make):

> to produce something, often using a particular substance or material

Here is a sentence that shows it being used in this way:

> I made this dress with the material that I bought last week